# How can goto a particular line or condition in Ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby

I want the code for the following case using Ruby (RoR):

```
 line no: 09
line no: 10         if(@yyyyy == nil)
line no: 11            do some operation here
line no: 12             then goto line no 10
line no: 13         end
l
```

I tried with `next`, `break`, & `goto`, but nothing is working.

Is there any keyword/statement to fulfill my scenario?

Comment: using goto is considered a bad programming habit

Answer (score 7):

Ruby doesn't support it by default, and, if you were to submit the code to http://codereview.stackoverflow.com, I'm sure they'd help you to rewrite/refactor the code.

You can probably use the `redo` command to simulate what you want. "Programming Ruby" says:

> redo repeats the current iteration of the loop from the start but without reevaluating the condition or fetching the next element (in an iterator).

That said, "[The Joke Is On Us: How Ruby 1.9 Supports the Goto Statement](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/2/29/the-joke-is-on-us-how-ruby-1-9-supports-the-goto-statement)" will give you insight into actually using a "goto" with Ruby, however, at that point, your code will not be portable or usable in a "stock" Ruby.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add my ruby version. I need to do this using Ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 1):

Please do check the following  URL:

> http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/2/29/the-joke-is-on-us-how-ruby-1-9-supports-the-goto-statement

As per many expert programmers, using the goto statement is a bad practice.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add my ruby version. I need to do this using Ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

```
catch :foo do
  for (aaa in @xxxxx)
    if(@xxxxx == nil)
      do some operation here
      throw :foo
    end
    for (bbb in @yyyyy)
      if(@yyyyy == nil)
        do some operation here
        throw :foo
      end
    end
    for (ccc in @zzzzz)
      if(@zzzzz == nil)
        do some operation here
        throw :foo
      end
    end
  end
end
```